# Can I safely install a firmware update from a Virtualbox guest OS?

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb, virtualbox, firmware

This is pretty simple, I think ...

I would like to install a firmware update in a MIDI controller. The device in question is an Arturia Minilab MkII keyboard controller, which interfaces to a computer via USB/MIDI.

As far as I know, the only way to install the update is to use Arturia's proprietary MIDI Control Center application. That program runs on Windows or MacOS, whereas I mainly use Linux and do not have a physical installation of any other OS. However, I do have Windows 10 installed as a VirtualBox guest OS on my Linux laptop.

I'm just wondering if the fact that Windows is communicating via a virtual USB port poses any particular risk in performing this operation?

Comment: A guest in a software virtualizing application uses the Host hardware and cannot install firmware in a guest machine. This must be done in the host machine.

Comment: @John: what exactly do you mean by "install firmware in a guest machine?" You understand that I want to install firmware to an external hardware device *from* the guest machine, right?

Comment: No you cannot do that. The firmware must be updated in the host machine. The keyboard must work in the Host and then it should work in the Guest.

Comment: @John: OK, we're not really communicating here. There is no question of the keyboard working or not; it works fine with the host (Linux) OS. Though I have no intention of *using* the keyboard with a guest OS, the MIDI Control Center software is needed to *configure* the device and to push firmware updates. 

I have installed the software in the Windows guest system, and it seems to function as intended for configuring the controller. Given that fact, I don't understand why you think I *can't* push the firmware update from it; my question was whether it is *safe* to do so.

Comment: @john the OP is not trying to upgrade the firmware of the computer but the firmware of a device attached to the computer by USB.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I have not tried to do this. I upgrade firmware of devices that are directly attached to a physical host machine.

Comment: @xenoid: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Never tried to update firmware this way, but I **suppose** there is no problem. It’s only bytes back and forth.